# Limit proof; can $\varepsilon=\delta$?

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, epsilon-delta

I am wondering about a beginner proof I am trying to do, and also a more general question.

I am working on the question, $$\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{x^2y^2}{x^2+y^2}$$

So I looked at a few cases and it seemed to me that it might be reasonable that the limit is 0, so I tried to do an epsilon delta proof.

that is, I am under the impression that if I can show that for any $\epsilon >0$ there exists a $\delta > 0$, such that if $0< \sqrt{x^2+y^2}< \delta $ then  $| \frac{x^2y^2}{x^2+y^2}-0|< \epsilon$ ( also I can remove the absolute value signs because we have only squares).

So then I thought I could do something like, $$x^2 \le x^2+y^2 \rightarrow \frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2} \le 1 \rightarrow \frac{x^2y^2}{x^2+y^2} \le y^2 \le x^2+y^2$$ ( using that $y^2 \le x^2+y^2$ as well)

But now I am not sure how to proceed, should I say let $\delta=\epsilon$ ? Is that even valid to say. Also, I have not looked at solutions or anything so I am not sure if my work is correct either, so i appreciate any comments/answers!

Thankyou.

Comment: Close. Take it $\sqrt{\epsilon}$.

Comment: Yes, $\delta$ is allowed to depend on $\epsilon$.

Comment: @Shalop Yea I understand that, but I was more asking can it actually = directly? i.e. $\delta = \epsilon$ ?

Comment: Consider $\lim_{x\to 0} x=0$. Then $\delta =\epsilon$ suffices, since $0<|x-0|<\delta\implies 0<|x-0|<\epsilon$. Your $\delta$ can be any function of $\epsilon$, given it actually implies the function being within $\epsilon$ of the limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Take $\delta = \sqrt{\epsilon}$. Let $(x,y) \in \mathbb R^2$:

$$||(x,y) - (0,0)||_2 < \delta \implies \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} <\delta \implies x^2 + y^2 < \delta^2 \implies x^2 + y^2 < \epsilon $$

etc.

Comment: Thanks, what is the little 2 beside the norm by the way?

Comment: My pleasure. It is to signify that this is the Euclidean norm. There are other types of norms: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29